# Exact list of Node core modules

Tags: node.js

I am looking for a way to get an exact up-to-date list of all Node.js core modules. Is there an NPM module that supplies such a running list? Somewhere in the annals of my life I had an answer to this question written down, but I don't remember it nor do I remember how good a solution it was.

Comment: After "About these Docs" and "Synopsis," Node's [API Documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/) is organized by module. They can also be found in the source files, [under the `lib` directory](https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/master/lib) (ignore files with `_` prefixes).

Comment: @johnathan I am look to get this info programmatically, without having to do some horrible web scraping LOL

Comment: Just see it live on [Tonic](https://tonicdev.com/npm/builtin-modules)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As of Node v9.3.0, you just do this:

```
require("module").builtinModules
[ 'async_hooks',
  'assert',
  'buffer',
  'child_process',
  'console',
  'constants',
  'crypto',
  'cluster',
  'dgram',
  'dns',
  'domain',
  'events',
  'fs',
  'http',
  'http2',
  '_http_agent',
  '_http_client',
  '_http_common',
  '_http_incoming',
  '_http_outgoing',
  '_http_server',
  'https',
  'inspector',
  'module',
  'net',
  'os',
  'path',
  'perf_hooks',
  'process',
  'punycode',
  'querystring',
  'readline',
  'repl',
  'stream',
  '_stream_readable',
  '_stream_writable',
  '_stream_duplex',
  '_stream_transform',
  '_stream_passthrough',
  '_stream_wrap',
  'string_decoder',
  'sys',
  'timers',
  'tls',
  '_tls_common',
  '_tls_legacy',
  '_tls_wrap',
  'tty',
  'url',
  'util',
  'v8',
  'vm',
  'zlib',
  'v8/tools/splaytree',
  'v8/tools/codemap',
  'v8/tools/consarray',
  'v8/tools/csvparser',
  'v8/tools/profile',
  'v8/tools/profile_view',
  'v8/tools/logreader',
  'v8/tools/tickprocessor',
  'v8/tools/SourceMap',
  'v8/tools/tickprocessor-driver',
  'node-inspect/lib/_inspect',
  'node-inspect/lib/internal/inspect_client',
  'node-inspect/lib/internal/inspect_repl' ]
```

see https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_builtinmodules

Answer (score 27):

If you don't mind accessing underscore-prefixed properties, `repl` exports a `_builtinLibs` array:

```
$ node -pe "require('repl')._builtinLibs"
[ 'assert',
  'buffer',
  'child_process',
  'cluster',
  'crypto',
  'dgram',
  'dns',
  'domain',
  'events',
  'fs',
  'http',
  'https',
  'net',
  'os',
  'path',
  'punycode',
  'querystring',
  'readline',
  'stream',
  'string_decoder',
  'tls',
  'tty',
  'url',
  'util',
  'v8',
  'vm',
  'zlib' ]
```

That list isn't as "complete" as the list provided by the `builtin-modules` module in that it does not include undocumented and similar modules.

Comment: I didn't test this, but I figure it's slightly better than a semi-static JSON file in a 3rd party library

Comment: 'repl' is also there in the list, but I think you removed it intentionally, as there is no point that it couldn't be there, since you are using that module to show the complete list! Well, its showing up on my PC

Comment: @AnkurShah I did not remove anything at the time. It was probably an error in node at that time.

Answer (score 3):

J4F: you can use the [github api](https://api.github.com) and get a list of files directly in JSON format.

```
var http = require('https')
var path = require('path')

var options = {
  hostname: 'api.github.com',
  path: '/repos/nodejs/node/contents/lib',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
             'user-agent': 'nodejs/node' 
  }
}

var req = http.request(options, (res) => {
  res.setEncoding('utf8')
  var body = ""
  res.on('data', (data) => { body += data })
  res.on('end', () => {
    var list = []
    body = JSON.parse(body)
    body.forEach( (f) => {
      if (f.type === 'file' && f.name[0]!=='_' && f.name[0]!=='.') {
        list.push(path.basename(f.name,'.js'))
      }
    })
    console.log(list)
  })
})
req.on('error', (e) => { throw (e) } )
req.end()
```

Answer (score 2):

33 modules are in the builtin-modules according to https://www.npmjs.com/package/builtin-modules.

```
36 according to core structures 
28 repositories in Git 
112 packages
```

It will take a long time to compile this list. Doing it as a research on node_core will be good option.

Answer (score 0):

## Execute this into your app:

```
console.log ( require('repl')._builtinLibs ); return;
```

to list all built-in modules.